# HOW do i inject new data in my firebase, making my own info posts

Tags: database, firebase-realtime-database

I just don't understand why my new posts are not showing in my Google play store App. I am conected to Firebase,i'm a beginner and its confusing with this firebase, i have an array list and i post daily new information, but doesn't appear, i have no users or login, just simple post on cardview with text.

Comment: Do i need some Reference or ValueListner? I didn't test the Read and write data from Firestore, because i didn't now what is used for, firebase added automatically the implemations and pluggin

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"